# Set differnet levels of logging for loggers in log4j

Tags: java, logging, log4j, httpclient

I am using log4j for my application - there I need to see all log messages, so I defined

```
# General configuration
log4j.rootLogger = ALL, ConsoleAppender

# Appender configuration
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern = %5p (%c) %m%n
```

But, after I started using Apache's HTTPClient library (which is awesome btw), my console got clouded up by its logging - everything was logged and I am not able to see the log output from my own application any more.

So how can I tell the HTTPClient library that it should only log `WARN` messages, while my own application still logs on `ALL` levels?

I create my application logger using

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j.properties");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite simple. Just add the below line.

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=WARN
```

Similarly, you can configure levels for any package `com.foo` or class `com.foo.Bar` by appending it to the prefix `log4j.logger` as follows:

```
log4j.logger.com.foo=MYLEVEL
log4j.logger.com.foo.Bar=DEBUG
```

Comment: You should add that the left part of this propertie consists of two parts: `log4j.logger`and `org.apache.commons.httpclient`. The second part names the package you want this log level to apply to.

Comment: @Tichodroma that's quite obvious to anyone who has used either log4j or HttpClient.

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it isn't :)

Comment: Be aware that log4j.logger.org.apache.commons.httpclient=WARN will log everything >= WARN, not only WARN.

Comment: @quaylar I think it's desirable, why would one want to just `WARN` and forget about `ERROR`s?

Comment: @adarshr - Of course, i just pointed it out because of Florians formulation to "only log WARN messages"..